# Whats the difference between sampler types(HttpClient 4,HttpClient 3.1 and Java)

Tags: jmeter

I am new to Jmeter.Under 'HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder' elment what is the difference between 
HttpClient 4,HttpClient 3.1 and Java Types?
which option will be best for recording?

regadrs.

Answer (score 6):

See the JMeter Documentation of Sampler [HTTP_Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request):

> HTTP Request - this has an implementation drop-down box, which selects the HTTP protocol implementation to be used:
>
> - Java - uses the HTTP implementation provided by the JVM. This has some limitations in comparison with the HttpClient implementations - see below.
> - HTTPClient3.1 - uses Apache Commons HttpClient 3.1. This is no longer being developed, and support for this may be dropped in a future JMeter release.
> - HTTPClient4 - uses Apache HttpComponents HttpClient 4.x.
> - Blank Value - does not set implementationon HTTP Samplers, so relies on HTTP Request Defaults if present or on jmeter.httpsampler property defined in jmeter.properties